# Loading a huge Python Pickle dictionary

Tags: python, pickle

I generated by pickle.dump() a file with the size of about 5GB. It takes about half a day to load this file and about 50GM RAM. My question is whether is it possible to read this file by accessing separately entry by entry (one at a time) rather than loading it all into memory, or if you have any other suggestion of how to access data in such a file.

Many thanks.

Comment: How about a database? http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: 5 GB wow, may i ask what are you trying to dump using Pickle ?

Comment: which kind of data do you have? I'm thinking in a [hdf5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) datafile

Comment: Your question is to vague to answer. What exactly do you pickle? Binary data, Text data, complex object-structures? Your question is only slightly more elaborate then: "Houston we got a problem!" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Before I go into the realm of sql (which I haven't seriously tried before) - do you know if it is possible to directly load the pickled file as an sql table, or must the file be saved in sql format (or could it be converted into one from my pickled one)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Serializing and De-serializing dictionaries/string is bound to take time and it increases with the size of the data. If your data is structured, consider using a relational database(MySQL, SqLite) as suggested by @FogleBird , if it is unstructured, try using a database like mongodb or couchdb which are pretty famous for storing key value pairs in json format.

Comment: Don: I totally agree, but it is a bit difficult to describe the type of data in this specific case, I suppose you could call it complex biological text data that consists of dictionaries of dictionaries (it is basically different attributes for each human gene).

Comment: Thank you Krishna, I will check out mongodb and couchdb.

Comment: So, it perfectly fits into a non-relational datafile. I **strongly** recommend you checkout HDF5, we use it a lot in storing big amount of numerical data with multiple levels and such...

Answer (score 7):

There is absolutely no question that this should be done using a database, rather than pickle- databases are designed for exactly this kind of problem.

Here is some code to get you started, which puts a dictionary into a sqllite database and shows an example of retrieving a value. To get this to work with your actual dictionary rather than my toy example, you'll need to learn more about SQL, but fortunately there are many excellent resources available online. In particular, you might want to learn how to use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), which is an "Object Relational Mapper" that can make working with databases as intuitive as working with objects.

```
import os
import sqlite3

# an enormous dictionary too big to be stored in pickle
my_huge_dictionary = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4}

# create a database in the file my.db
conn = sqlite3.connect('my.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table with two columns: k and v (for key and value). Here your key
# is assumed to be a string of length 10 or less, and your value is assumed
# to be an integer. I'm sure this is NOT the structure of your dictionary;
# you'll have to read into SQL data types
c.execute("""
create table dictionary (
k char[10] NOT NULL,
v integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (k))
""")

# dump your enormous dictionary into a database. This will take a while for
# your large dictionary, but you should do it only once, and then in the future
# make changes to your database rather than to a pickled file.
for k, v in my_huge_dictionary.items():
    c.execute("insert into dictionary VALUES ('%s', %d)" % (k, v))

# retrieve a value from the database
my_key = "A"
c.execute("select v from dictionary where k == '%s'" % my_key)
my_value = c.next()[0]
print my_value
```

Good luck!

Comment: Or just use [sqlitedict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlitedict), to preserve sanity.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an object oriented database, if your data is heterogeneous - using ZODB - which internally uses pickle, but in a way designed, and time proved - to manage large amounts of data, you probably will need little changes to your application

ZODB is the heart of Zope - a Python application server - which today powers Plone among other applications.

It can be used stand-alone, without all of Zope's tools - you should check it, doubly so if your data is not fit for SQL.

http://www.zodb.org/